# Uploading Excel to MySQL - trouble with enum field

Tags: mysql, excel, sqlyog

I am using SQLYog Ultimate.

I have a table with an enum field that can get one of 3 numbres - 0,1,2
I made 0 a default number (wrote it as default in the table)

I am creating a table from an excel file and then insert the table content to my table.
The problem is only with the enum field:

1. If i leave this column empty, then it stays empty and doesnt get the default value
2. If i enter "0" as number in excel, then it stays empty when i insert to my table
3. If i enter "0" as text in excel, then it stays empty when i insert to my table

How am i suppose to define it in excel so i can upload it with the zero value?

The steps of my work:
1. Prepare the EXCEL file
2. Upload the EXCEL into a new temp table that is created by EXCEL definition
3. INSERT INTO MY TABLE (SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE)

Comment: if `numbers ENUM('0','1','2')` then `INSERT INTO t (numbers) VALUES(2),('2'),('3');` gives '1','2','2'. 0 as number does not exist. Does it add a default value if you use  `INSERT INTO t (numbers) VALUES(NULL)`?

Comment: There is a roundabout. You can create a table just for your import and use usual int or nvarchar instead of ENUM. Then copy the data from the table to your table.

Comment: KEIV - If i dont insert anything i receive a warning "field cant be NULL" and it stays empty.

Comment: As i said - i upload EXCEL meaning create a NEW table and then copy it to my table. INT or VARCHAR dont work - the field in the new table is 0 but in my table with enum it becomes empty

Comment: Sorry, It seemed impossible to me that a copy fails. I will create a local database on my computer and see what happens with ENUM.

Comment: `insert into tenum(enumf) VALUE(default)` works

Comment: I will write a proper sql statement as an answer in several minutes

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy a table with int to a table with ENUM and the following worked in phpmyadmin:

```
INSERT INTO tenum (enumf) SELECT '0' FROM excel
```

Instead of writing all the columns in SELECT you can also try

```
ALTER TABLE excel MODIFY numb VARCHAR(255);
```

As I cannot see the structure of your table it is difficult to write the exact code. The first line works for me and supposes that you do not have any meaningful value for ENUM field in excel (I understood that way from the original question). If it has meaning then you can write IF statement in SELECT (IF(numb=0,'0',numb)). But it is extremely hard to write code that works if I do not understand the type of numb field and the ENUM definition in your table.

Structure of table tenum:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tenum` (
  `enumf` enum('0','dsx') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

structure of table excel:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `excel` (
  `numb` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I dont understand. You tell to your table "tenum" what is excactly the value of enumf? Why "SELECT '0'? And if i have sometimes another value (from the enum)

Comment: It means it works in sql and if you have other values you can substitute only the default value. Show me two variants of you int (or is it string?) field in excel table and I will rewrite the code.

Comment: Just give me an example of excel table in mysql with two rows.

Comment: The value of enumf can be `enumf enum('0','dsx') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` and I assign it a default value of '0'